# how to optimize data structure for read for mongo or sql to client

Tags: javascript, python, sql, mongodb

I'm trying to optimize for read here and while my question is presumably tech agnostic, my case uses mongodb for a database.

I have an array of file objects like so that I can get from a /api/files endpoint:

```
[{id: 1, name: 'foo', size: 500},
{id: 2, name: 'bar', size: 600},
{id: 3, name: 'baz', size: 700}]
```

that I will retrieve on the app's load.

I will then be able to choose one of these files to add metadata to it in a form.

this is where I have the option of either:

1. using a /api/files/1 (:id), which would cost a network roundtrip
2. I can try to find the file info that I want to alter by running `files.find(file => file.id === 1)`, which might be not super performant.
3. Change the way I store "files" data completely in mongo as nested objects instead of an array like so

```
{
1: {id: 1, name: 'foo', size: 500},
2: {id: 2, name: 'bar', size: 600},
3: {id: 3, name: 'baz', size: 700}
}
```

which would mean I might lose the ability to use mongodb's findOne method or its SQL equivalent.

I was wondering which of these options would be best for read performance.  Thanks!

Comment: why would find not be performant? Presumably mongodb would give you a free index on id which would simply be an index seek in most db technologies.

Comment: @Brenden, the extra call to the backend and related mongo retrieval (option 1) would involve a latency penalty, whereas a local search on the cached list would be unindexed (option 2).  I was trying to see which would be the lesser of two evils

Comment: By local cache you mean you find all ahead of time, and have it exist somewhere on the client to avoid round trip calls?

Comment: yes. exactly. I'd be pulling up all the files, kind of like running ls on a directory to show the contents of the directory and that would be cached locally on the client.

Comment: It sounds like there are two issues here. 1) Optimizing reads on the server 2) Minimizing requests on the client. For 1, Assuming you're app is running on a single machine, just cache your data in memory. You will have to evict this data as writes are made. 2) As long as the overall data length is reasonable just preload the entire collection. if the data is stable you might want to save it into local storage for some length of time.

Comment: You should profile your app first to see if you need to do anything because caching is can of worms. If you need it or just want to experiment there are plenty of resources on line for this.